# Need help using java to read a file, insert trim command, edit the strings, and then save the file as an output

Tags: java, string, text, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have two different ways to read the file but I am not sure how to proceed to converting the text to a string and then an if then statement like...

```
 if string contains ":"                                                       
   true string = "string"
   false string = ,,"string" 

 package test;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("foo.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
        String trim;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

But I don't believe I am using the trim command appropriately

Comment: I use BufferedReader usually. But it might interest you to know that there is such a thing as a FileWriter in java. And that is how you would get your data out.

Comment: what is the error?  what's inside the foo.txt file? why not use the same file for both examples?

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono you probably meant `FileReader`.

Comment: @hfontanez No, filewriter, because he has to read the file. Which he can do, then change it, which he can figure out. But it didn't seem that he had code for writing the file back out. So I suggested filewriter.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono got it. For a second I thought you were suggesting an alternative to `BufferedReader`.  The first sentence in your comment doesn't support the second, which is why I got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't really communicate clearly the intent of the program.  What exactly are you trying to do?  If your file is text-based, there is no "conversion to String" needed.  Also "save the file as an output" isn't clear either.  Do you want to save a new file, overwrite the existing file, or append the existing file.  All of these scenarios are handled differently. Taking this by parts:

**First point**: Your `Scantest` class works. Given a file `foo.txt` in the project folder, the class will print out the contents of the file.

**Second point**: Your class `ReadStringFromFileLineByLine` works with my own `foo.txt` just like the first class.  So, there might be something wrong with your `test.txt` file. This is probably the most important thing when testing (making all conditions equal). If the conditions for testing are not equal, the tests will most likely be inconclusive (which is why I suspect happened in your case).

**Third point**: None of your classes attempted to make any modifications to the obtained strings or made modifications to the file.  If you were to write to a file, you have to consider the following: Append vs. Overwrite.  All it takes is the use of a simple `boolean` value:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()); // overwrites contents of file
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); // appends to file
```

The `FileWriter` single argument contructor calls the two-argument constructor passing `false` to it. Therefore, the `FileWriter` overwrites instead of appends.  This is important because if you handle the file line by line, it is possible that at the end, your file will contain only the last line you "modified."  If you choose to append, the new String will be added to the end of the line. So this is not good either.  If you want to process a file line by line, made modifications to any given line, AND save the line to the same file, your best option is to use `RandomAccessFile`.  This class allows you to write 'X' number of characters starting on a given offset.  In this case, this "offset" is the "address" of the current line; putting it simply: the offset is equal to the number of characters already processed.  So, for the first line, the offset is 0, for line 2 is the number of characters in line 1, and so forth.

I can add this as an update if you need it, but I did not see anything in your code that attempted to change the file in any way.  I was just going by your title.

Comment: I guess I am not explaining this very well because I am still learning. I can read the text fine but I am trying to figure out which of the two classes would be better to use. Ultimately the goal is to find replace leading and trailing white space and then edit the text  using the if/then and saving the appended text. The problem I have is that I understand which comands I need to use but don't understand how I should use them.

Comment: Read my post. The answer is there. The technique you use to read the file is really immaterial for what you are trying to do.  If you want to "read and replace", it is probably best if you use `RandomAccessFile`. This class gives you the option to start reading/writing at a specific offset. A simple `FileWriter` append won't do the trick because `append` writes to the end of the file and not the current line.  The other alternative is to hold the contents of the file in some buffer, modify it at will, and then write (overwrite) the entire contents of the buffer as a whole.